# Login Using Active Directory in Asp.net Mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, active-directory, forms-authentication

I am new for Active Directory authentication. Need to create login using active directory. Please help me with explained example or link where I can learn to create active directory login

My web.config file:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Service/Index" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
</authentication>

      <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
     <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a " 
          connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
          connectionProtection="Secure" 
          connectionUsername="bos\user10" 
          connectionPassword="user@101"
          attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://fontier.bos.com:389/DC=fontier,DC=bos,DC=com" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And my login action method is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LoginUser(LoginUser login, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                     
           
            //MembershipProvider domainProvider = Membership.Providers["ADMembershipProvider"];
            //if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(login.UserName, login.Password))
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(login.UserName, login.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName,true);
                if(Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Service");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
        }

        return View(login);
    }
```

Logout action:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("LoginUser", "User");
    }
```

Here, I am getting error : The specified domain or server could not be contacted.
I googled a lot but couldn't get anything useful....Please give your valuable suggestion for this....Thanks.

Comment: To me it looks like the application was not able to connect to this ldap server on a network level. Please verify from the machine where the application is running on that this ldap connection string is actually reachable (meaning you can create LDAP connection using i.e. ldapsearch).

Comment: @raspy how can I verify ldap server from machine...can u tell me the process..

Comment: This server hosting the application, is it a Windows or a Unix machine?

Comment: @raspy Windows Active directory which hosted on   windows server 2012

Comment: @raspy I use active directory username as connectionUsername ="bos\user10" ......is it necessary to add Domain(bos) before username.......or can I use directly the username of Active directory......